# How do you get string interpolation working on a javascript onlick event using a repeat.for

Tags: aurelia

```css
/* *********************************************************************************************

How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu [Tutorial]
"How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu" that was specially made for DesignModo by our friend Valeriu Timbuc. 

Links:
http://vtimbuc.net/
https://twitter.com/vtimbuc
http://designmodo.com/futurico
http://vladimirkudinov.com
http://rockablethemes.com

********************************************************************************************* */

/* Reset */

.accordion,
.accordion ul,
.accordion li,
.accordion a,
.accordion span {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}

.accordion li {
 list-style: none;
}

/* Layout & Style */

.accordion li > a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 110px;
 padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
 height: 32px;

 color: #fdfdfd;
 font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);

 background: #6c6e74;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a,
.accordion > li:target > a,
.accordion > li > a.active {
 color: #3e5706;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
 
 /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
 background: #a5cd4e;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); 
}

.accordion li > a span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 7px;
 right: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
 font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
 background: #404247;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a span,
.accordion > li:target > a span,
.accordion > li > a.active span {
 color: #fdfdfd;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);
 background: #3e5706;
}

/* Images */

.accordion > li > a:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 margin: 4px 8px;

 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.accordion li.files > a:before { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.accordion li.files:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.files:target > a:before,
.accordion li.files > a.active:before { background-position: 0px -24px; }

.accordion li.mail > a:before { background-position: -24px 0px; }
.accordion li.mail:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.mail:target > a:before,
.accordion li.mail > a.active:before { background-position: -24px -24px; }

.accordion li.cloud > a:before { background-position: -48px 0px; }
.accordion li.cloud:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud:target > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud > a.active:before { background-position: -48px -24px; }

.accordion li.sign > a:before { background-position: -72px 0px; }
.accordion li.sign:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.sign:target > a:before,
.accordion li.sign > a.active:before { background-position: -72px -24px; }

/* Sub Menu */

.sub-menu li a {
 color: #797979;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

 background: #e5e5e5;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.sub-menu li:hover a { background: #efefef; }

.sub-menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.sub-menu li > a span {
 color: #797979;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.sub-menu em {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: 14px;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Functionality */

.accordion li > .sub-menu {
 display: none;
}

.accordion li:target > .sub-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- *********************************************************************************************

How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu [Tutorial]
"How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu" that was specially made for DesignModo by our friend Valeriu Timbuc. 

Links:
http://vtimbuc.net/
https://twitter.com/vtimbuc
http://designmodo.com/futurico
http://vladimirkudinov.com
http://rockablethemes.com

********************************************************************************************* -->

<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <title>jQuery Accordion Menu</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordionmenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

 <style type="text/css">body{background:url(img/bg.png) repeat;width:960px;margin:0 auto}.footer{margin-top:50px;text-align:center;color:#666;font:bold 14px Arial}.footer a{color:#999;text-decoration:none}#wrapper-250{width:250px;margin:0 auto;}</style>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>

<body>

 <img src="img/title.png" alt="">

 <div id="wrapper-250">

  <ul class="accordion">
   
   <li id="one" class="files">

    <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
     
     <li><a href="#test"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>
     
  

    </ul>

   </li>
   
   <li id="two" class="mail">

    <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
     
     
     <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>

    </ul>

   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </div>

 <div class="footer"><p>By <a href="http://vtimbuc.net/">Valeriu Timbuc</a> for <a href="http://designmodo.com">DesignModo</a>.</p></div>
 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

   // Store variables
   
   var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
    accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

   // Open the first tab on load

   accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

   // Click function

   accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

    // Disable header links
    
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show and hide the tabs on click

    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
     accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
     $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
     accordion_head.removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
    }

   });

  });

 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

aurelia-framework 1.1.4

Given:

```
   <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="files" 
       onclick="alert('${row.title}');" style="cursor:pointer;">
       <a href="${row.href}">${row.title}</a>
    </li>
```

I would expect the alert to display the current row.title but the alert does not even fire.

Comment: `alert(row.title)`?

Comment: Quick test and that doesn't work, the `row` var is only in scope inside of the `<li>` element. What are you actually trying to achieve - I guess the end game isn't to have the alert firing?

Comment: Don't think you can use `row` inside `onclick`. You can create a function inside the `class` and use `click.delegate`.

Comment: @thebluefox `row` is available for `<li>` element as well.

Comment: @thebluefox if you look at the skeleton-nav they use row on the <li> element    <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">

Comment: Poorly explained possibly in my original comment. It's not in scope within the onclick.

Comment: @adiga What do you mean create a function inside the class.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @dan check [this gist](https://gist.run/?id=e95386f229af6bb4aba163a83ad74c77). I added a method called `onNavClick` inside `app.js`. Are you expecting something like this?

Comment: I added a code snippet.  What I want to be able to do is click on a header or a sub menu and navigate to a page.  I was able to accomplish this using onclick="location.href='#/customer-list'

Comment: @adiga Your solution answered my question.  Please add it as an answer.  One more thing if you want to take a look I normally use    myroute.navigateToRoute('detail') in the onclick event but for some reason it is not working

Comment: @dan does the route `detail` exist? Is `myroute` an instance of aurelia's `Router`?

Comment: @adiga Yes I do it is working now, I just had a typo.  Thank you. If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it correct.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`click.delegate`](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/3) to add a click event handler to an element in aurelia.

```
<template>
 <li click.delegate="onNavClick(row)"  repeat.for="row of router.navigation">
     <a href="${row.href}">${row.title}</a>
  </li>
</template>
```

In your `app.ts` `class`

```
onNavClick(row){
   alert(row.title);
}
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.run/?id=e95386f229af6bb4aba163a83ad74c77)